# Randomness of seeded cryptographically secure random number generator

Tags: random, pseudo-random-number-generator, seed

If I generate a large true random number and I seed a CSPRNG with it, then can the output of this CSPRNG be used anywhere where there is a need for a true random number?

For example, if Alice and Bob both know the seed, then could the output of a CSPRNG seeded with this seed be used to securely generate any number of one time pads they can use, which would have the same security properties of TRNG one time pads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSPRNG does not create true randomness. Any true randomness returned must come from somewhere, in this case the seed. If you seed it with 1000 bits of true randomness, then the CSPRNG can return **at most** 1000 bits of **true** randomness but never more.